# AutoValue not working in Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, auto-value

I am using `Eclipse IDE for Java Developers Version: Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)` and trying to use Google's `AutoValue` library in my project.

I have included it as a Maven dependency:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.auto.value/auto-value -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.auto.value</groupId>
        <artifactId>auto-value</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And trying to use it:

```
@AutoValue
public abstract class Person {

    @AutoValue.Builder
    public static abstract class Builder {

    }

    public static Builder builder() {
        return new AutoValue_Person.Builder();
    }   
}
```

The problem I am having is that `AutoValue_Person` cannot be resolved to a type. This should be an auto-generated class.

I also installed the `m2e-apt` plugin for Eclipse, and set `Annottion processing mode` to: "Automatically configure JDT APT", but this didn't solve the problem.

Is there a way to get it work in Eclipse?

Comment: check you .metadata/.log file. Probably you suffer https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/898

Comment: Perhaps you'll find an answer in this other thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844399/eclipse-autovalue-class-fails-to-build